# Conditional or absolute convergence of an integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{1+x^{2}}dx$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I ran into a few problems where i had to check absolute\conditional convergence of a few integrals.

I'm sure theres a method to check this, i just can't find the trick.

I wan't help with one of the problems so that i can get the rest on my own.

> Check absolute or conditional convergence of the integral:
>
> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{1+x^{2}}dx$$

thanks in advance,

yaron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare with $$\int_0^\infty {dx\over 1 + x^2}$$.

Comment: can't do because there's a difference between 0->1 and          1->infinity

Comment: $|\sin(x)| \le 1$ for all $x$.

Comment: ok, got it. thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely convergent. The intuition here is that the absolute value of our function is "small" when $x$ is large.

Since $|\sin x| \le 1$ for all $x$, we have
$$\left|\frac{\sin x}{1+x^2}\right| \le \frac{1}{1+x^2}.$$
The integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$
converges. If we want to be formal about the proof, note that
$$\int_0^M \frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\arctan M,$$
and $\arctan M \to \frac{\pi}{2}$ as $M\to\infty$.

So by **Comparison** $\int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin x|}{1+x^2}\,dx$ converges, and therefore $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{1+x^2}\,dx$ converges absolutely.

We give a somewhat more messy alternate approach. Break up our original integral as
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sin x}{1+x^2}\,dx +\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin x}{1+x^2}\,dx.$$

The first integral is no problem, a respectable function over a finite interval. For the second, note that 
$$\left|\frac{\sin x}{1+x^2}\right| \le \frac{1}{x^2}$$ if $x\ge 1$.
But $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}$ converges.

In order to make comparisons, we need to have a collection of integrals that we know converge or diverge. One of the most important classes of integrals to compare with are the integrals 
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^p}.$$
This converges if $p\gt 1$, and diverges if $p\le 1$.